# jquery css height selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to set equal height in div which have class name "modelCode" so i made a small function to do so but when i am running this function it is setting height 0px in elemeny style. Before that i used .height() method which is working perfactly but i want to this with css height method any guess. Thanks in advance

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function equalHeight(group) {
        var tallest = 0;
        group.each(function () {
            var thisHeight = $(this).css('height');
                if (thisHeight > tallest) {
                    tallest = thisHeight;
                }
         });
         group.css('height',tallest);
    }

    function setequalheight() {
        equalHeight($(".modelCode"));
    }

    $(document).ready(function () { setequalheight() });
    </script>
<style>
    .modelCode { width:200px; float:left; border:solid 1px #F00}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modelCode">i am new text </div>
    <div class="modelCode">i am new text <br />i am new text <br />i am new text <br />i am new text <br /></div>
```

Comment: @DanielNWerner What makes you think `.each()` runs async?

Comment: It doesn't. Deleted my comment to reduce bad info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will work now

```
function equalHeight(group) {
var tallest = 0;
group.each(function () {
    var thisHeight = $(this).css('height');
    thisHeight = parseInt(thisHeight.substr(0 , (thisHeight.length - 2)));
    //alert(thisHeight)
    if (thisHeight > tallest) {
        tallest = thisHeight;
    }


});

group.css('height',tallest);
}
```

the problem is that .css('height') returns a string value, so you have to parse it to integer to compare which is bigger value

Comment: thanks pal singh now i understand what is the difference between .height() and css height function

Comment: if it was correct, i hope you wont mind it marking as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

When you use jQuery's `css` method you have to provide the entire value. In this case you provide it with some integer, when really you want to give it the integer plus "px". It's the same as writing "height:40" in css (if the integer is 40).

Try changing

```
group.css('height',tallest)
```

to

```
group.css('height',tallest+"px");
```

Comment: it will not work, because the value of tallest is 0 all the time